# JavaScript Change in custom module not refreshed by deployment

Tags: magento2, javascript, static-content-deploy

I am going crazy right now. I made a change in a JavaScript file in a custom module which is installed via composer from my own repo. But I can't, under any circumstances, get those changes reflected in the frontend. I also use Cloudflare, but it is paused right now to not store any files in cache. I tried the following:

- `static:content:deploy (and yes I deployed for my specific language as well)`
- `rm -R pub/static/* & static:content:deploy & cache:flush`
- `rm -R var/view_preprocessed & rm -R pub/static/* & static:content:deploy & cache:flush`
- `Disabling Varnish & cache:flush`
- `setup:upgrade & setup:di:compile & static:content:deploy & cache:flush`

The only possibility to see my changes is when I copy my changes to the already deployed and minified file in the pub/static directory... .

I have merging & minification for JavaScript enabled in Magento backend and static file signing is also active. But I can't, under any circumstances, get my changes be respected in the deployed files. I have no more ideas to try...

Comment: What is your Magento version? Once you deploy can you able to find that changes in pub file?

Comment: 2.3.1 and no, that's what I wrote. The changes are not present in the deployed file. But I can see the changes, when I copy my code directly into the already deployed pub/static file. So it's not an issue of browser caching or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow This Step:-**

```
sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/adminhtml/ pub/static/_requirejs pub/static/deployed_version.txt var/cache var/page_cache var/generation var/view_preprocessed var/session generated/code

sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade

sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US -f

sudo php bin/magento cache:flush

sudo chmod -R 777 generated/ var/ pub/ app/
```

Comment: Thanks but I already did that numerous times